# String inside Dataframe with colons to integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have this DataFrame:

```
C1   C2
A    2:3:1:7
B    2:1:4:3
C    2:1:1:1
```

I need to sort the integers in `C2`, keeping the colons.

The output should look like this:

```
C1   C2
A    1:2:3:7
B    1:2:3:4
C    1:1:1:2
```

The example above is for understanding, this is the output I have so far:

```
{'_c1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}, '_c2': {0: '2:3:7:9:1:8:6:1', 1: '5:1:3:9:4:6:8', 2: '6:7:5:0:9', 3: '3:1:5:5:2:7', 4: '1:2:8:3:8:9:7:3:4:6:5:5:1:5'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
df['C2'] = df['C2'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: x.sort() or x).str.join(':')
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  C1       C2
0  A  1:2:3:7
1  B  1:2:3:4
2  C  1:1:1:2
```

Comment: ``df.assign(C2 = df.C2.str.split(':').map(sorted).str.join(':'))``

Comment: I'm getting this error: "Can only use .str accessor with string values!", but I already use astype str, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Send me the output of `print(df.head().to_dict())`, please.

Comment: There are no strings with colons in that data...

Comment: Give me one moment.

Comment: {'_c1': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}, '_c2': {0: '2:3:7:9:1:8:6:1', 1: '5:1:3:9:4:6:8', 2: '6:7:5:0:9', 3: '3:1:5:5:2:7', 4: '1:2:8:3:8:9:7:3:4:6:5:5:1:5'}}

Comment: Try this code: `df['_c2'] = df['_c2'].str.split(':').apply(lambda x: x.sort() or x).str.join(':')`

Answer (score 1):

No NaN's, you can use:

```
df['C2_new'] = [':'.join(sorted(x.split(':'))) for x in df['C2']]
```

Output:

```
  C1       C2   C2_new
0  A  2:3:1:7  1:2:3:7
1  B  2:1:4:3  1:2:3:4
2  C  2:1:1:1  1:1:1:2
```